# React-Query: Is there an alternative way to update useQuery staleTime besides setQueryDefaults?

Tags: react-query

I'm trying to do this:

```js
function useReactiveStaleTimeQuery() {
    const [staleTime, setStaleTime] = useState(1000);
    const { data } = useQuery(queryKey, queryFn, { staleTime, notifyOnChangeProps: ["tracked"] })
}
```

But setQueryDefaults feels weird:

```js
function useReactiveStaleTimeQuery() {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const [staleTime, setStaleTime] = useState(1000);

    useEffect(() => queryClient.setQueryDefaults(queryKey, { staleTime }), [staleTime]);

    const { data } = useQuery(queryKey, queryFn, { notifyOnChangeProps: ["data"]});

    return data;
}
```

It's possible that only the `queryKey` and/or `queryFn` is watched by `useQuery` but I'm not entirely sure (don't have time to go through the source code) but what I don't understand is how is it possible that the `enable` option is watched but `staleTime` is ignored. Docs don't say anything about using `staleTime` as a thunk like `initialDataUpdatedAt`.

Answer (score 0):

> but what I don't understand is how is it possible that the enable option is watched but staleTime is ignored.

so this usually works:

```
function useReactiveStaleTimeQuery() {
 const queryClient = useQueryClient();

 const [staleTime, setStaleTime] = useState(1000);

 const { data } = useQuery(
  queryKey,
  queryFn,
  { staleTime }
)

 return [data, setStaleTime];
}
```

Once you update the `staleTime`, the query will notice it. However, unlike `enabled` (which works on a per-observer level), there is only one query in the cache, so there can only be *one* staleTime.

This is important if you have two observers (use the custom hook twice). You can have one enabled and one disabled query, but you cannot have `staleTime: 1000` and `staleTime: 500` on the same query. As far as I know, the shorter one "wins".

So yeah, controlling the `staleTime` with state works, but I think it would be better to store it globally and not with local state on a per hook level.

Comment: Thanks @TkDodo, my problem is I keep a list of item summaries that have a "lastUpdated" key so I'm trying to use that to dynamically calculate slateTime so I can toggle a "Data out of sync" button or something, so I kinda need to have staleTime tracked on a per-observer basis.

Comment: Why do you need staleTime to toggle a button? If that flag is part of `data`, just use that to calculate what you need for the button.

Comment: Thanks again @TkDodo Well think of it this way, I have a list of item summaries & each item summary has a "lastUpdated" and "expiresIn" fields, so when I mount the details component I want to be able to set staleTime from those 2 fields, its like initialDataUpdatedAt except this isn't initalData. I wanted to also use those fields to show an "sync" button in the item summary list view in case "expiresIn" is, well expired.